# validation doesn't work activesupport-3.2.13 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

After installing rvm, ruby and rails i write same code validation in my model

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description, :price, :weight
  validates :price, :weight, numericality: {greater_than: 0} , presence: true 
end
```

But when i start rails console and print

```
tem1 = Item.create(name: "d", price: 0, weight: 1)
```

I have error

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.13)
2.0.0p0 :001 > item1 = Item.create(name: "d", price: 0, weight: 1)
NoMethodError: undefined method `￼validates' for #<Class:0x007ffa968ec810>
    from /Users/epoleshchuk/RailsProject/test2/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:55:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/epoleshchuk/RailsProject/test2/app/models/item.rb:5:in `<class:Item>'
    from /Users/epoleshchuk/RailsProject/test2/app/models/item.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/epoleshchuk/RailsProject/test2/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load'
    from /Users/epoleshchuk/RailsProject/test2/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `block in load_file'
    from /Users/epoleshchuk/RailsProject/test2/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/epoleshchuk/RailsProject/test2/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `load_file'
    from /Users/epoleshchuk/RailsProject/test2/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:353:in `require_or_load'
    from /Users/epoleshchuk/RailsProject/test2/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/epoleshchuk/RailsProject/test2/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
    from /Users/epoleshchuk/RailsProject/test2/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
    from /Users/epoleshchuk/RailsProject/test2/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/epoleshchuk/RailsProject/test2/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/epoleshchuk/RailsProject/test2/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/epoleshchuk/RailsProject/test2/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from scexit
```

Also gem install activesupport -v 3.2.13 doesn't help me.

Rails 3.2.13
ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
rvm 1.19.3 (stable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read your error carefully:

```
undefined method `￼validates'
```

It looks like you have some strange Unicode character in there before `validates`, that you need to remove.

Comment: Thank you very match, i type in the head of my model 
#coding: utf-8 and it work !

Answer (score 0):

Also got similar type of unknown method error even though i never used that method when
starting rails server.
This may be due to some words added by mistake in the controller or model class files.check your app to see whether the word "validates" has been added somewhere unknowingly especially before and after class definitions.